# Jenkins - Parallel stages with docker for PHP

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I'm new with Jenkins, and I would like to get almost the same behavior as in GitLab CI for one of my PHP project.

I use Docker to test my project on several PHP versions.

What I want ?

Running build and test in parallel.

- Build creates my application, sources come from a git repository, and I run the `composer install` command.
- Dockerfile is stored in `/var/lib/jenkins/Docker`
- My Dockerfile has a parameter (`PHP_VERSION`) which allow me to choose the PHP version I want
- `customWorkspace` seems to work

Here is my Jenkinsfile to do so :

```
updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'pending'

pipeline {
    agent none
    post {
      failure {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'failed'
      }
      success {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'success'
      }
    }
    stages {

        stage('build') {

            parallel {
                stage('build-php5.4') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg PHP_VERSION=54'
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            customWorkspace './build-php5.4'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'pwd'
                        sh 'ls'
                        sh 'rm -Rf composer.lock vendor'
                        sh 'composer install'
                    }
                }

                stage('build-php7.0') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg PHP_VERSION=70'
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            customWorkspace './build-php7.0'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'pwd'
                        sh 'rm -Rf composer.lock vendor'
                        sh 'composer install'
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        stage('tests') {

            parallel {
                stage('test-php5.4') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg PHP_VERSION=54'
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            customWorkspace './build-php5.4'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'pwd'
                        sh 'php --version'
                        sh 'php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests'
                    }
                }

                stage('test-php7.0') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            additionalBuildArgs  '--build-arg PHP_VERSION=70'
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            customWorkspace './build-php7.0'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'pwd'
                        sh 'php --version'
                        sh 'php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result :

[image]

It looks good, but it isn't, and I don't really understand the underlying behavior.

As you can see, the test-php54 stage uses the last created Docker container :

[image]

I'm sure I'm wrong on a lot of steps, but do you think I can do it this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the main problem.

The fact is I use the same Dockerfile, but with different parameters.
If I create one Dockerfile for PHP 5.4 and another one for PHP 7.0, the stages are parallelized correctly.

```
updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'pending'

pipeline {
    agent none
    post {
      failure {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'failed'
      }
      success {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'success'
      }
    }
    stages {

        stage('build') {

            parallel {
                stage('build-php5.4') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            filename 'Dockerfile-php5.4'
                            customWorkspace './build-php5.4'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'rm -Rf composer.lock vendor'
                        sh 'composer install'
                    }
                }

                stage('build-php7.0') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            filename 'Dockerfile-php7.0'
                            customWorkspace './build-php7.0'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'rm -Rf composer.lock vendor'
                        sh 'composer install'
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        stage('tests') {

            parallel {
                stage('test-php5.4') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            filename 'Dockerfile-php5.4'
                            customWorkspace './build-php5.4'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'php --version'
                        sh 'php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests'
                    }
                }

                stage('test-php7.0') {
                    agent {
                        dockerfile {
                            dir '/var/lib/jenkins/Docker'
                            filename 'Dockerfile-php7.0'
                            customWorkspace './build-php7.0'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'php --version'
                        sh 'php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the share @Ulti I had the same confusion around the parallel, which was compounded by that fact I ran my pipeline on a docker image, I neede to run it in
`pipeline {
    agent none` and then split off the branches, which was not how my original pipeline was arranged in serial loops, so the old pipeline loop I already had polluted my thinking.